# CSS layout based on (flex) items content

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I've written some JavaScript to accomplish this, but it's performance is slowing down my component and its not clean so I'm struggling to find more efficient CSS solution which would optimize it. I've searched the web with no effect.

So basically we have this template (simplified):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All 3 `.box`'s are taking 1/3 (ie `calc(100% / 3)`) and rendered in a row.

If at least one of that `box`'s content overflowing it's dedicated space - all 3 suppose to render in column (ie `flex-direction: column`). Is there any way to achieve this using `flexboxes` and no JavaScript?

Note: this chunk is rendered inside a responsive component(dropdown), that is 100% of it's grid cell. And it may take 100% of the screen as well as 10%. So I cant use any media-queries here.

Comment: Could you provide a solution you have? It's hard for me to picture what are you trying to accomplish. And could you add a snippet?

Comment: Solution I have is part of the angular component and it's using some bundled logic to get to component's ViewChild and it's nativeElement.offsetWidth before it's rendered. To simplify, it goes like this: verticalLayout = ((box2Width + box3Width) > containerWidth) ? true : false

Comment: Anyways I`ll add a plunkr soon.

Answer (score 0):

if you want wrap last item, you can use `flex-wrap:wrap;` in flexbox container and if flex items don't have specific width you can use min-width.

if you want change direction of flex box in one breakpoint you can use `@media` like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:680px){
    .flexContainer{
        flex-direction:column;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this template is part of the component, that is part of the grid. So I can't use media-queries here... Thanks anyways

Comment: And because of container - only 2 last `boxes` would wrap. It's crucial for me to wrap all 3 items in a column. And I can't get rid of the container since its a separate component with it's logic.

Comment: if you select .container in css all elements with this class selected and when you change direction to column all of that's child change these behavior (box1,container,box2,box3)